# Null Pointer Exception while mocking Optional Parameters

Tags: java, testing, junit, java-8, mockito

My code is of the form:

```
public String getDeliveryDestinations(final RequestContext requestContext {
    final Accessor accessor = requestContext.getAccessor().get();

    final GroupAccessor groupAccessor = accessor.getGroupAccessor();

    final String groupId = groupAccessor.getGroupId();


    if(groupId.equals("s1") return "Type1";
    else return "type 2";


}
```

For testing this, i wrote the following:

```
@Test
public void getDestinationsDestinations_empty() throws Exception {


    Accessor accessor = mock(Accessor.class);
    GroupAccessor groupAccessor = mock(GroupAccessor.class);
    //*mockRequestContent is Mocked*
    when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor().get()).thenReturn(accessor);
    when(accessor.getGroupAccessor()).thenReturn(groupAccessor);
    when(groupAccessor.getGroupId()).thenReturn("s1");

    String destinationResult = provider.getDeliveryDestinations(mockRequestContext);
    assertEquals(destinationResult,"Type1");

}
```

I get a NPE at, 
 when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor().get()).thenReturn(accessor);
I don't know why!

Any leads would be very helpful :)

Comment: Well, you never told the mockRequestContext what to return for getAccessor(). So it returns null. And you can't call get() on null. Or it returns an empty Optional (assuming that's the return type). And trying to get the value of an empty Optional throws an NPE.

Comment: @JBNizet  what should be written?
when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor()).thenReturn(Optional.of(accessor));
when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor().get()).thenReturn(accessor);
Is this correct? Actually i am fairly new to this.

Comment: No. Just `when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor()).thenReturn(Optional.of(accessor));` You can't tell a real optional what to return when its get() method is called. You can only do that with mocks. And Optional.of() doesn't return a mock. Why don't you test it by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when `getAccessor()`need to return an optional you can do it like this:

```
Accessor accessor = mock(Accessor.class);
GroupAccessor groupAccessor = mock(GroupAccessor.class);

Optional<Accessor> optAccessor = Optional.of(accesor)
when(mockRequestContext.getAccessor()).thenReturn(optAccessor)
when(accessor.getGroupAccessor()).thenReturn(groupAccessor);
when(groupAccessor.getGroupId()).thenReturn("s1");
```

Comment: Technically you are right. But helping someone testing train-wrecks (a.b.c) is not what we should be doing. The design of the SUT is poor and it should be fixed, not the test that struggles to work with this poor design!

Comment: but you do not know if the code of  `GroupAccessor` can be changed. And not not help with the test because the design of the stuff to test is poor - well that's not the way how I see SO.

Comment: but you can at least suggest the real solution even if you plan to show how things can be done - and that IMHO would be much better, regards